# How to "parametrize" angular component in html?

Tags: angular

The question title is not correct but don't know how to ask this. Anyway I have 2 tab-components that are exactly the same but they have different table components (that inherit same base class) on them:

tab-base.component.ts:

```
export class TabBaseComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() tabIndex: number;
    @Input() dataObject: any;

    public parentDataObject: any;
```

tab-base.component.html:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

some-data-tab.component.ts:

```
export SomeDataTabComponent extends TabBaseComponent implements OnInit {
   // this doesn't really have any code because all logic is in base class
```

some-data-tab.component.html:

```
 <h1>Parent table</h1>
 <app-some-table-table
    [dataObject]="parentDataObject">
 </app-some-table>
 <h1>Child table</h1>
 <app-some-table-table
    [dataObject]="dataObject">
 </app-some-table>
```

another-data-tab.component.ts:

```
export AnotherDataTabComponent extends TabBaseComponent implements OnInit {
   // this doesn't really have any code because all logic is in base class
```

another-data-tab.component.html:

```
 <h1>Parent table</h1>
 <app-another-table>
    [dataObject]="parentDataObject"> 
 </app-another-table>
 <h1>Child table</h1>
 <app-another-table 
   [dataObject]="dataObject"> 
 </app-another-table>
```

Then there's the table components:

tab-base.component.ts:

```
// this is never used directly
export class TableBaseComponent implements OnInit {
    // input from tab
    @Input() dataObject: any;
```

tab-base.component.html:

```
<app-properties-table [dataSource]="dataSource" [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns"></app-properties-table>
```

some-table.component.ts:

```
// this doesn't have own template
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-table',
  templateUrl: '../base-table/base-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../base-table/base-table.component.scss']
})
export class SomeTableComponent extends BaseTableComponent implements OnInit {
```

some-table.component.ts:

```
// this doesn't have own template
@Component({
  selector: 'app-another-table',
  templateUrl: '../base-table/base-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../base-table/base-table.component.scss']
})
export class AnotherTableComponent extends BaseTableComponent implements OnInit {
```

The question is that how can I avoid having 2 almost the same htmls (some-data-tab.component.html AND another-data-tab.component.html) where only the table-component name is changed? So I would like to have something like this:

tab-base.component.html:

```
 <h1>Parent table</h1>
 <app-table-base>
    [dataObject]="parentDataObject"> 
 </app-table-base>
 <h1>Child table</h1>
 <app-table-base 
   [dataObject]="dataObject"> 
 </app-table-base>
```

some-tab.component:

```
// Somehow tell that the table-component should be app-some-table / SomeTableComponent
```

another-tab.component:

```
// Somehow tell that the table-component should be app-another-table / AnotherTableComponent
```

I've done this kind of thing creating the objects dynamically using ComponentFactoryResolver and directive etc. However I would like to do this in html if it's possible.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? If `some-tab.component` and `another-tab.component` have the exact same html and there is no logic in the `corresponding .ts` files, maybe you don't need two o three different components, especially if you're extending the `tab-base.component`. Do you want to nest the tabs? What kind of data are you inputting to the components?

Comment: i know this is horrible question but didn't really know how to ask this properly. but what i do have is 2 different kind of tables that share same base component. but they are not same. that's why i need to have 2 different table components and also 2 different tab components because i don't know how to "parametrize" the only thing that is different. which is the table component. i don't want to nest tabs or do anything else not stated in the question. my goal is to not have 2 almost same tab compnent htmls: some.data-tab.component.html and another-data-tab.component.html.

Comment: What is the difference between the table components? Above you say they use the same HTML…

Comment: i think i just have to come up with more simple example